# Method for building a test fixture for the 4294A impedance analyzer?

Tags: rf, impedance, test-equipment

I have an Agilent 4294A, a 40Hz-110MHz impedance analyzer, but no test fixtures to use. Unfortunately the official test fixtures are out of my price range so I need to build some. After reading through the [Agilent application note on Impedance Measurements](https://www.keysight.com/ca/en/assets/7018-06840/application-notes/5950-3000.pdf), I found section 3.1.5 which describes the 4TP test fixture that I would like to make (as it is apparently the best method for this instrument). Figure 3-8 from the application note is shown below.

Can the test fixture be built exactly as shown in figure 3-8b and still operate over the full frequency range? or are there other considerations I'm missing?

If it can be built the same way, does the wire connecting the coax shields together also need to be shielded, or will any piece of wire do?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked for third-party test fixtures? The spacing of the BNC terminals is standard, and a test fixture from some no-name company may work just as well as the Keysight one.

Comment: *"does the wire connecting the coax shields together also need to be shielded..."* Nope.  Just use a wire

Comment: @Hearth I've looked into a few other options (TLKB1 and TL89T1 from B&K, IM9110 from Hioki, LCR-xx series from gwinstek) however they are all rated for <10MHz (most are for <1MHz) so I'm concerned they will introduce error at higher frequencies

Comment: @Hearth Third-party rarely use 4TP, though. I know ours (ST26047) don't. But even HP only used 4TP in the 10Ω impedance range with the 4284 - IIRC the BNC connectors are shorted with relays for all ranges above, changing the setup to 5T. If you can't guarantee the wiring to have the same wave impedance all the way through, 4TP or 5T won't matter much anyway.